# Python 3.7 problems importing module without editing sys.path or using relative paths

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have created an application using Python 3.7 with following structure

```
main_app.py 
   /foo/bar.py 
   /foo/constants.py
```

What is the best practice to import class A from bar?

Currently in main_app.py I'm importing module bar with following code

```
import foo.bar

a = foo.bar.A()
```

However, for some reason, I got "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'constants'" error when running main_app.py.

Here is bar.py

```
import constants

class A:

    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

Using relative import, this works

```
from . import constants

class A:

    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

Anyway, clean way to use just absolute imports would be appreciated.

One possible solution for using absolute imports is to install packages:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name = 'foo',
    packages = find_packages(),
)
```

Then in foo.bar we can use absolute import:

```
import foo.constants

class A:

    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

Comment: So what does `bar.py` look like…?

Comment: Are you importing `constants` in `bar.py`?

Comment: There is nothing related to `constants` in the code you've shown us. Please include the relevant code.

Comment: Added bar.py example

Comment: Replace `import constants` with `from . import constants`.

Comment: Why this is actually needed? It works but I can't understand why other method does not work.

Comment: I don't have time now to write an answer, but have a look at 'relative imports'

Comment: I know the concept, but was originally trying to use just absolute imports

Answer (score 0):

I imported it using

```
from . import constants
```

and it works. However would be nice to use just absolute imports

Answer (score -1):

I think your problem is not how you import class A but instead your bar.py file cannot find this module called "constants".
you can try add

```
import sys
import os
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

before importing constants

afaik, the import sequence for python is that it will look on the python lib install dir instead of the same directory you're in, hence you need to add it to the path

Comment: It is not totally good. If I call the script from other location then the `sys.path.append('.')` will append my current location to path. To use `os.path.dirname(__file__)` instead of `".'`would be better to get path of directory of file.

Comment: alright, thanks for the correction.
I will correct the code

Answer (score -2):

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'constants'. This mean your python didn't have the 'constants' module. So you just need to install it as well. Search in google like python constant module and you will get this https://pypi.org/project/constants/. Follow this and you install that module.